# ¿Cómo vincular una aplicación web en una app Android y iOS?

Tags: android, ios

Tengo conocimientos en diseño y, desarrollo web pero, ya en aplicaciones para dispositivo móviles desconozco su lenguaje aunque nada difícil seguro dado a qué es fácil adaptarse a cualquier lenguaje sabiendo otros lenguajes de programación.

Pero para no iniciar a tan fondo en diseño en aplicaciones `Android` y `iOS` nuestro diseño o aplicaciones web son 100% adaptables a cualquier dispositivo móviles, usamos menos recursos para hacer de un sitio web ligero, con optimización y, velocidad de carga.

Cómo puedo hacer que una página web se convierta en una **app** `Android` y `iOS` de manera simple, nativa así como un `iframe` cargar mi sitio web en una **app** como un simple:

```
    <iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: La pregunta parece basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Yo desarrollaría una API que sirva el contenido de la página Web para ser consumido por la aplicación. Es mucho más ligero y extendible a cualquier situación.

Comment: @A.Cedano tendría que desarrollar una aplicación de cero?

Comment: Sí, tienes que desarrollar una App móvil para cada plataforma, o, pasar por caja y hacer un desarrollo multiplataforma. Una etapa sencilla cuando se empieza sería por ejemplo mostrar el contenido de tu Web en la App directamente (en un componente del tipo `WebView`). Pero quizá eso no sea suficiente, porque siempre como que te quedas a medias, en mi opinión los usuarios de dispositivos móviles son más exigentes y no se conforman con una App que de la impresión de que estás en el navegador de internet. Aparte de eso, aunque sea lo más sencillo no es lo más ligero.

Comment: Yo empecé con una App para Android e iOS por ese camino (usando webView), porque gran parte de su contenido ya estaba en una web, pero al final me lancé por programar una App en sí y no tiene nada que ver. El contenido es el mismo, tanto en la web como en la App, pero en la App ciertas cosas cambian, los diseños, los menús, las pantallas. Mi opción final fue programar una API que me sirva en forma de JSON los datos que hay en la web y presentarlos en la App usando sus componentes propios. Es un poco más trabajoso, pero vale la pena. Cuando tienes la estructura, lo demás va sobre ruedas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Se ve muy complejo cuando los datos que obtienes son basados en PHP y, MySQLi ese mismo código sirve o se debe cambiar, me imagino que el diseño a repartir en el bucle debe ser el diseño de las apps así como se repite código HTML

Comment: Mi contexto es el mismo: los datos se obtienen usando `mysqli`, pero en vez de obtenerlos como página HTML obtengo solamente los datos (que puede ser contenido HTML o no) en un JSON el cual recibo en la App para mostrarlo en un `TextView` [he aquí algunas pantallas de ejemplo](https://www.liturgiaplus.app/breviario/). Todo es más ligero y más rápido así porque sólo traerías el contenido, y luego en la App de forma nativa te ocupas de presentarlo o formatearlo como lo desees.

Comment: En mi caso la App tienes más de una docena de pantallas distintas y cada una de ellas consume contenido (miles de páginas) que es solicitado al sitio web a modo de API. [Este es un ejemplo](https://deiverbum.org/api/2020/01/oficio/20200203). La App pide esos datos al servidor vía esa URL y el servidor consulta la BD, busca los datos y los devuelve en forma de JSON. La App los recibe, los procesa y los muestra.  Si creas modelos de datos y te ayudas con librerías como Gson vas sobre ruedas una vez has montado la estructura de la App y todo de forma nativa y sin intermediarios.

Comment: @A.Cedano interesante la información Cedano gracias por compartirla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar cualquier framework para una aplicación híbrida como:

1. Ionic
2. Flutter
3. Xamarin

Entre las más conocidas: con ellas creas los **HTML** y **CSS** necesarios para tu aplicación.

La otra opción Nativa es agregar en el **ViewController** inicial un **Webview (Android)** ó **WKWebview (iOS)** apuntando a tu sitio en donde se encuentra alojado tu aplicación.

Te dejo un ejemplo en Swift para que tengas una idea.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView! //link al Web View

    override func ViewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.ec") // la URL de tu Aplicación Web
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!) // creas el request con la URL

        self.webView.load(request) // cargas en el Web View el contenido del Request
    }
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image: Webview en el Storyboard]

**Ejecución en el simulador**

[image: Run]

Al ejecutar la aplicación, el Webview mostraría el contenido de tu Aplicación Web.

Comment: Interesante es una buena alternativa mantener la web así, hasta que más adelante la desarrolle como debe ser desde cero desde una aplicación mientras que funcione así, creo que no estaría mal.

Comment: Un aplicación que solo consiste en un WebView apuntando a una url no pasará los controles de Apple en el App Store. Ten por seguro que no te permitirán publicarla. Puedes leer los requisitos en el siguiente enlace: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality. Especialmente en el punto 4.2

Comment: @Bicho Hola, que IDE utilizó aquí disculpe, como se llama?

Comment: @Valentina es Xcode, el IDE nativo de Apple. Solo está disponible para una MacBook.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que solocitas no es factible, convertir un sitio web a una aplicacion movil no tiene sentido, tengo varios años de experiencia desarrollando apps y lo unico que te puede decir es que la experiencia en la Web y los dispositivos moviles son dos cosas muy diferentes. Te recomiendo utilizar **React Native** el cual te permite utilizar React para construir aplicaciones nativas tanto para Android y IOS escribiendo codigo en Javascript.

Comment: Esta respuesta promete ser buena, si se desarrolla más… con su forma actual es menos útil de lo que podría llegar a ser.

Comment: @BrayanLoayza Gracias por responder, pensé que sería más fácil cuando un sitio web cumple con las características de una aplicación adaptada a todos los dispositivos móviles.

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], ya que esto parece mas un comentario/recomendación que una respuesta en si

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/195109)

Comment: No le pueden pedir una respuesta más desarrollada si la pregunta es tan amplia...

Comment: @JheymanMejia Si di una alternativa usar React Native, ahora la solucion que menciona Eric realmente no es una solucion, que sentido tiene embeber una pagina web en una apicacion, considero que las WebViews se debe utilizar en casos muy particulares, pero no como una solucion para migrar un sitio web a dispositivos moviles.

Comment: @Alfabravo para aclarar una pregunta tan amplia está la sección de comentarios.

Comment: @BrayanLoayza el mensaje que te dejo es automático desde la cola de revisión a publicaciones de baja calidad. Puedes mejorar tu respuesta (sólo si así lo deseas) revisando el enlace que te comparte el compañero Aprendiz más arriba.