# Por qué aparece pantalla negra en WebKit Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo este código de Webkit en Xcode y al arrancar me aparece pantalla negra. He probado con distintas url y no funciona, este código fue visto desde un tutorial con el fin de aprender a generar un web view en iOS.

Quizás se esté utilizando algo que ya se encuentre obsoleto dentro de xcode?,en el código me refiero

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak
  var webView: WKWebView!
  @IBOutlet weak
  var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let url = "https://www.google.cl/"
      let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url) !)
      self.webView.load(request)
      self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)

    }

  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String ? , of object : Any ? , change : [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any] ? , context : UnsafeMutableRawPointer ? ) {

    if keyPath == "loading" {
      if webView.isLoading {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.isHidden = false
      } else {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.isHidden = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Te marca algún error en el debugger del Xcode? Está casi similar a mi respuesta aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326398/c%c3%b3mo-vincular-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-web-en-una-app-android-y-ios/326416#326416

Comment: Si comentas la línea del self.webView.addObserver, tienes el mismo resultado?.

Comment: Lo intentaré, el código que presentas Eric en tu link lo hice hace un rato y funcionaba bien, hasta que comenzó a aparecer un error de que esperaba un nil en la línea donde se encuentra self.webView.load(request), te comento cualquier observación. Gracias @Eric